# Radius authentication for OpenVPN in pfSense

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, openvpn, pfsense, radius

I have a pfSense Firewall with OpenVPN against RADIUS Server configured in a Windows Server 2008 R2.

The RADIUS server is configured in pfSense, but when I try the Authentication (Diagnostics -> Authentication) I always get an Authentication Failed error.

In Windows event viewer I get a message, identifying correctly the user trying to log (domain\user), but saying "Code 16, User does not exist or incorrect password". I've tried with a couple of users, one of them Administrator.

The network policy says any user in the domain can log. I have no idea to keep trying. Any hint?

Comment: Nevermind, I rebooted Windows Server, and everything's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try rebooting the Windows Server?